# Use dtedit function gives me error: unused arguments

Tags: r

I am using Dtedit library in R- shiny, the code worked before, but now it shows me

```
Error in DTedit::dtedit(input, output, name = "xx", thedata = xx,  : 
  unused arguments (input.choices.reactive = list(names = names_reac, names_rList = ...._)
```

what is problem? it is the first time I am using  `Dtedit`

My expectation is that something has changed in this functions. That why it gives error

Comment: Welcome to SO, Shtx! It's hard to say at the moment; I'm inferring https://github.com/jbryer/DTedit (there is no `DTedit` on CRAN), but we don't know how you're using it. Please make this question *reproducible*. This includes sample code you've attempted (including listing non-base R packages, and you have already included the error message, good!), sample *unambiguous* data (e.g., `data.frame(x=...,y=...)` or the output from `dput(head(x))` into a [code block]), and intended output given that input. Refs: https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269, [mcve], and https://stackoverflow.com/tags/r/info.

Comment: https://rpubs.com/DavidFong/DTedit